# generate multiple RDDs at the same time

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd

The original fileRDD is created by

```
sc.wholeTextFiles(path)
```

and the key of fileRDD is file name, the value is file content.
When I traverse a file content(value), I can get a lot of information. So I want to generate multiple RDDs after traversing a file. For example: I define three class

```
public class Interface implements Serializable
public class VPNInstance implements Serializable
public class Equipment implements Serializable
```

after using map operation:

```
fileRDD.map(traverse function)
```

return

```
RDD<Interface>, RDD<VPNInstance> and RDD<Equipment>
```

at the same time. Otherwise, I need to traverse the file content three times to generate the three RDD.

So is there a solution to generate multiple RDDs at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, write one traverse function that creates objects like this:

```
public class Record implements Serializable {
    private Interface interface;
    private VPNInstance vpnInstance;
    private Equipment equipment;
}
```

After mapping dataset use `cache()` or `persist()` to avoid recomputing.